# Can you argue the current decrease along the two inductor pieces of a transformer using impedance?

Tags: transformer

I'm looking for a way to explain it other than using energy conservation/ power equal logic.

[image]

in this we derive the relation between current in each coil by equating powers and then using the ratio of voltages from faraday's law. Now, would there be any way to show the current change without Faraday law/ an intuitive perspective of it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean. I don't follow your title question - more details are needed to explain what you mean.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free design house, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and findings so far in considerable detail with a schematic. The schematic tool here is easy to use. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: Yes there would  : Maxwell's Equations for one.

Comment: can you demonstrate

Comment: What do you mean by "current decrease along the two inductor pieces"? It does not compute in my head. Are you talking about why the primary and secondary RMS currents might be different?

Comment: Ahhh I asked this question like a long time ago but I was asking, how the current changes as we move from the coil on left of inductor to the one on right

Comment: the current through the primary coil and one thru secondary coil is different

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the inductor is a series wire with no major leakage paths, the current will be consistent over the length of the Inductor.

What can vary is:

- the magnetic flux density over the various turns of the inductor,
- The voltage drop per turn or turn segment, as this is related to the inductance of that particular piece,
- The Resistance per turn or segment, this also effects the voltage drop, as this usually changes with temperature.
- capacitance between adjacent turns

Pretty much a real world inductor has a lot of non ideal elements that can convert the energy in the inductor in various ways, and in variable ways across its cross section, e.g. the wires may be moved by the EMF, which converts to noise. you have thermal losses, you may capacitivly couple to other nodes. you may induce current into a shorted or partial turn adjacent to the inductor.

Comment: I had slightly misphrased my question. Sry

Comment: I feel it still is valid, the electrons don't dissapear to the other half of the transformer, there motion generates an EM feild that pushes them in the other half, thus ignoring leakage paths, the current will be consistent across the coil, but the other parameters can vary.